# spring cloud config server cannot bind to gitlab

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I am using Spring springCloudVersion, "2021.0.3" to setup a Config Server that uses my gitlab account for its files.  I created a deploy token with premissions:

read_repository, read_registry, write_registry, read_package_registry, write_package_registry

and then I use those in the spring server application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=config-server
spring.application.version=0.1.0
server.port=8012

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://gitlab.com/[account]/[repo]
spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip-ssl-validation=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir=https://gitlab.com/[account]/[repo]
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=[my-token-username]
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=[my-token-password]
```

I was getting errors on startup about not binding the base directory until I put the same uri there as in ***spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri*** (they are now identical but it feels wrong)

When I try to startup my ConfigServerApplication I get the following:

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'multipleJGitEnvironmentProperties': Could not bind properties to 'MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties' : prefix=spring.cloud.config.server.git, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir' to java.io.File
2022-06-30 12:04:53.020  INFO 1594 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-06-30 12:04:53.026  INFO 1594 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-30 12:04:53.033 ERROR 1594 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir' to java.io.File:

    Property: spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir
    Value: https://gitlab.com/[account]/[repo]
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 9:40
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.io.File (caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not retrieve file for URL [https://gitlab.com/[account]/[repo]]: URL [https://gitlab.com/[account]/[repo]] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: https://gitlab.com/[account]/[repo]
```

I don't know what file it is trying to access - in that repo I have

- README.md
- application.properties

and I would think the properties files is what it is trying to access?

I have tried using both my account credentials and the deploy token with the same results.  I did not try the deploy key because this will not be access locally, but via cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Finally tracked it down - I had to add:

spring.profiles.active=native

and remove

spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir